# Flutter: Content hidden by phones bottom Navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, screen-orientation

In my **register** screen, part of the content(at the bottom) is hidden by the phone's bottom navbar. The content is only visible when I close the bottom navbar.

What I want to achieve is, whenever the bottom navbar is displayed on the phone, I want content that is hidden by it to be pushed upwards for visibility and whenever the navbar is removed from sight, I want the content to remain at it's position.

Here is my code.

```
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Padding(
        padding:
            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                "Register Account",
                style: headingStyle,
              ),
              Text(
                "Complete your details or continue \nwith social media.",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.05), // 5%
              SignUpForm(),
              SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.03), // 3%
              Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
                SocialCard(
                  icon: "assets/icons/google-icon.svg",
                  press: () {},
                ),
                SocialCard(
                  icon: "assets/icons/facebook-2.svg",
                  press: () {},
                ),
                SocialCard(
                  icon: "assets/icons/twitter.svg",
                  press: () {},
                )
              ]),
              SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(15)),
              Text(                        <--- HIDDEN FROM VIEW
                "By continuing you confirm that you agree with our Term and Condition",  
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Get Screen Size
class SizeConfig {
  static MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static double screenWidth;
  static double screenHeight;
  static double defaultSize;
  static Orientation orientation;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
    orientation = _mediaQueryData.orientation;
  }
}

// Get the proportionate height as per screen size
double getProportionateScreenHeight(double inputHeight) {
  double screenHeight = SizeConfig.screenHeight;
  // 812 is the layout height that designer use
  return (inputHeight / 812.0) * screenHeight;
}
```

Visual of the problem
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try implementing SafeArea, which takes care of this. This widget acts as a padding for the phones that have this kind of issue with unreachable content. It was originally thought for the iPhones without touchId at first, but if I'm not wrong fixes this problem on Androids as well.

This is the link to the documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html

You can wrap your containers (And your scaffold as well), or your widgets individually, as follow:

```
SafeArea(
   minimum: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
   child: Text('Your Widget'),
)
```

In your case I would wrap your entire Scaffold into a SafeArea this way:

```
SafeArea(
 child: Scaffold(
  ...
 )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your entire widget inside a [`SafeArea`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html)

This would ensure additional padding is put, to account for System-Based intrusions like the Status Bar, Nav Bar, Notch, etc.